# How to filter object in one array using propery in another in javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-5

**First Array**

```
const firstArray = [
{
   "value": "306",
   "label": "All"
},
{
   "value": "316",
   "label": "Tips"
},
{
   "value": "315",
   "label": "News"
},
{
   "value": "32",
   "label": "Jobs"
}]
```

**Second Array**

```
const secondArray = [
{
   name: "name",
   description: "desc",
   image: "path_image",
   culture: [{
     name: "name",
     value: "32"
   }]
},
{
   name: "name",
   description: "desc",
   image: "path_image",
   culture: [{
     name: "name",
     value: "32"
   }]
}];
```

Trying to filter my `firstArray` with only keeping the object with the value corresponding to `32`.

Still learning Javascript and it's in a React Native Project. They changed some info of the API and it was working when I only had : `culture":"32"`

**Code :**

```
let newOrigin = [...new Set(this.state.secondArray.map(product => product.culture))],
visibleOrigin = firstArray.filter(item => newOrigin.includes(item.value));

this.setState({ displayOrigin: visibleOrigin });
```

How to get the **value** inside the array **culture**.

Any advice, any help ? Thank you.

Comment: you want to filter which one? first or second array?

Comment: You need to get 1st value from array `culture`, and it has index `0`

It will work like this ```visibleOrigin = firstArray.filter(item => newOrigin.includes(item.culture[0].value));```. or you can use destructiring syntax ```visibleOrigin = firstArray.filter(({culture}) => newOrigin.includes(culture[0].value));```

Comment: @JiachenGuo I want to filter the first array to only display "Jobs". My Component is a dropdown. So I want to re-render the data with the filtered one.

Comment: `firstArray.filter(f => f.value==='32');` gives me array of objects where value is 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. I found a solution to my issue. Here's the code :

```
_nameFunction = () => {
    let filteredSecondArray = [...new Set(this.state.secondArray.map(o => o.culture[0].value))];
    this.setState({
        firstArray: this.state.firstArray.filter(item => filteredSecondArray.includes(item.value))
    })
}
```